# Test if a python instance method is the same function as a provided by a class

Tags: python, methods

I have a variable that points to a specific class instance's method.
Lets say there is a class called `Client` that implements a method `get`.
A single instance called `client` is created for `Client`, and a variable `get_func` is assigned with client's `get`.

For example, lets assume I have the following simplified code:

```
class Client:
    def get(self):
        print("This is the get function!")

client = Client()
get_func = client.get
```

I have little actual control over `get_func` and how it's used, I cannot change that.

I would now want to make sure `get_func` has the `Client.get`.

The trivial test `get_func == Client.get` does not work, as `get_func` is a bound method of a specific `Client` instance.
I also cannot get the `client` instance directly (but a way to get the `self` of a bound method is a valid option, if only I knew how to do that)

Comment: Try `get_func.__func__ is Client.get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Client.get` is either a *function* object (Python 3), or an *unbound method* (Python 2). `Client().get` on the other hand, is a *bound method*. Methods are wrappers around a function object, recording the instance they are bound to (if there is an instance) to pass in as the `self` argument. See the [*Python descriptor How-to*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) as to how Python produces methods from functions.

You can unwrap both a bound method and an unbound method to get the underlying function object that they wrap, and test that, with the `__func__` attribute:

```
get_func.__func__ is Client.get   # Python 3
get_func.__func__ is Client.get.__func__ # Python 2, unwrap the unbound method
```

If you need to make your code compatible with both Python 2 *and* 3, you could create a simple helper function:

```
def unwrap_method(f):
    return getattr(f, '__func__', f)
```

and use that:

```
unwrap_method(get_func) is unwrap_method(Client.get)
```